# How can I arrange the text in order to be centered?

Tags: tables, tabularx, adjustbox

I create a table with diffrente values and I want to have a "title" for the two columns. I want to move the text "MP" and "Canny" a little bit on the left ( I want to be between the text "Acc" and "Coef Dice"). I have tried to  delete one of the symbols "&" but it doesn't work.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\small
\begin{tabular}{rrlrrrrrr}
& & && \rowfont{\large}MP& & &  \rowfont{\large}Canny\\
    \hline
 & Img. &Imagine BSBD&Acc&Coef  Dice &  & Acc & Coef Dice\\ 
  \hline
& 1 & 103070.jpg & 0.9017 &0.1789 & &0.8298 & 0.1767\\
& 2 & 104055.jpg & 0.9238 &0.2694 & &0.8530 &0.1864\\
& 3 & 106025.jpg & 0.9391 &0.2594 &&0.9487 &0.2145\\
& 4 & 108004.jpg & 0.8563 &0.3738 &&0.7539 &0.2291\\
& 5 & 108005.jpg & 0.8213 &0.1583 &&0.7878 &0.1477\\
& 6 & 108082.jpg & 0.8572 &0.0816 &&0.8296 &0.0885\\
& 7 &  109053.jpg &0.9166 & 0.1930 &&0.8273 &0.1682\\
&8 &  113044.jpg & 0.8967 &0.2802 &&0.7997 &0.1675\\
& 9 & 123057.jpg &0.9250 & 0.1407 &&0.8370 &0.14906\\
& 10 & 130026.jpg & 0.8718 &0.0879 &&0.8162 &0.0770\\
& 11 & 160068.jpg & 0.8691 &0.0968 &&0.8519 &0.1166\\
&  12 & 16077.jpg & 0.8822 &0.2614 &&0.7978 &0.1866\\
&  13 & 163014.jpg & 0.9182 &0.2778 &&0.8629 &0.2020\\
& 14 & 163085.jpg &0.8387 &0.1144 &&0.8113 &0.1778\\
&  15 & 167062.jpg &0.8928 &0.2264 &&0.9528 &0.2685\\
&  16 & 196027.jpg & 0.9358 &0.2596 &&0.9142 &0.2472\\
&  17 & 247003.jpg & 0.8020 &0.1571 &&0.7488 &0.2289\\
&  18 & 253027.jpg & 0.8421 &0.3308 &&0.8348 &0.2869\\
&  19 & 291000.jpg & 0.7741 &0.1585 &&0.6862 &0.1015\\
& 20 & 296007.jpg & 0.9638 &0.1927 &&0.8589 &0.1119\\
&  21 & 304034.jpg &0.7805 &0.2185 & & 0.7024 & 0.1522\\
& 22& 326038.jpg  &0.8490 &0.3106 & &0.7688 &0.1652\\
& 23& 326085.jpg &0.8739 &0.1824 &&0.7880 &0.09560\\
& 24& 38092.jpg &0.8941 &0.4058 &&0.8103 &0.2324\\
& 25 & 41033.jpg &0.9461 &0.2834 &&0.8725 &0.1701\\
& 26&  42049.jpg &0.9506 &0.5688 &&0.9260 &0.3500\\
& 27& 43074.jpg &0.9004 &0.2247 &&0.8771 &0.1814\\
& 28& 69015.jpg &0.7865 &0.3290 && 0.7787 &0.2924\\
& 29& 69040.jpg &0.7371 &0.0876 & &0.7128 &0.1199\\
& 30 & 8023.jpg &0.9478 &0.0895 & &0.8611 &0.1016\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{.}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: should look alright now -- the first image shows the centering of MP and Canny -- in the second image the vertical lines have been removed-- `S` type columns with the `siunitx` package have been added for correct alignment of the numbers

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a `booktabs` based solution, with `siunitx` for the numeric data.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

% an ad hoc command for the second column header
\newcommand{\csplit}[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}%
}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  c
  >{\ttfamily}r
  *{3}{S[table-format=1.4]}
  S[table-format=1.5,group-digits=false]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Img. & \csplit{Imagine \\ BSBD} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MP} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Canny} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){5-6}
     &                          & {Acc} & {Coef Dice}    & {Acc} & {Coef Dice} \\
\midrule
 1 & 103070.jpg & 0.9017 & 0.1789 & 0.8298 & 0.1767\\
 2 & 104055.jpg & 0.9238 & 0.2694 & 0.8530 & 0.1864\\
 3 & 106025.jpg & 0.9391 & 0.2594 & 0.9487 & 0.2145\\
 4 & 108004.jpg & 0.8563 & 0.3738 & 0.7539 & 0.2291\\
 5 & 108005.jpg & 0.8213 & 0.1583 & 0.7878 & 0.1477\\
 6 & 108082.jpg & 0.8572 & 0.0816 & 0.8296 & 0.0885\\
 7 & 109053.jpg & 0.9166 & 0.1930 & 0.8273 & 0.1682\\
 8 & 113044.jpg & 0.8967 & 0.2802 & 0.7997 & 0.1675\\
 9 & 123057.jpg & 0.9250 & 0.1407 & 0.8370 & 0.14906\\
10 & 130026.jpg & 0.8718 & 0.0879 & 0.8162 & 0.0770\\
11 & 160068.jpg & 0.8691 & 0.0968 & 0.8519 & 0.1166\\
12 &  16077.jpg & 0.8822 & 0.2614 & 0.7978 & 0.1866\\
13 & 163014.jpg & 0.9182 & 0.2778 & 0.8629 & 0.2020\\
14 & 163085.jpg & 0.8387 & 0.1144 & 0.8113 & 0.1778\\
15 & 167062.jpg & 0.8928 & 0.2264 & 0.9528 & 0.2685\\
16 & 196027.jpg & 0.9358 & 0.2596 & 0.9142 & 0.2472\\
17 & 247003.jpg & 0.8020 & 0.1571 & 0.7488 & 0.2289\\
18 & 253027.jpg & 0.8421 & 0.3308 & 0.8348 & 0.2869\\
19 & 291000.jpg & 0.7741 & 0.1585 & 0.6862 & 0.1015\\
20 & 296007.jpg & 0.9638 & 0.1927 & 0.8589 & 0.1119\\
21 & 304034.jpg & 0.7805 & 0.2185 & 0.7024 & 0.1522\\
22 & 326038.jpg & 0.8490 & 0.3106 & 0.7688 & 0.1652\\
23 & 326085.jpg & 0.8739 & 0.1824 & 0.7880 & 0.09560\\
24 &  38092.jpg & 0.8941 & 0.4058 & 0.8103 & 0.2324\\
25 &  41033.jpg & 0.9461 & 0.2834 & 0.8725 & 0.1701\\
26 &  42049.jpg & 0.9506 & 0.5688 & 0.9260 & 0.3500\\
27 &  43074.jpg & 0.9004 & 0.2247 & 0.8771 & 0.1814\\
28 &  69015.jpg & 0.7865 & 0.3290 & 0.7787 & 0.2924\\
29 &  69040.jpg & 0.7371 & 0.0876 & 0.7128 & 0.1199\\
30 &   8023.jpg & 0.9478 & 0.0895 & 0.8611 & 0.1016\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{This is the caption}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want to enlarge the table to the text width, which I'd avoid, you can use `tabular*` rather than scaling.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

% an ad hoc command for the second column header
\newcommand{\csplit}[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}%
}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  c
  >{\ttfamily}r
  *{3}{S[table-format=1.4]}
  S[table-format=1.5,group-digits=false]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Img. & \csplit{Imagine \\ BSBD} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MP} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Canny} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){5-6}
     &                          & {Acc} & {Coef Dice}    & {Acc} & {Coef Dice} \\
\midrule
 1 & 103070.jpg & 0.9017 & 0.1789 & 0.8298 & 0.1767\\
 2 & 104055.jpg & 0.9238 & 0.2694 & 0.8530 & 0.1864\\
 3 & 106025.jpg & 0.9391 & 0.2594 & 0.9487 & 0.2145\\
 4 & 108004.jpg & 0.8563 & 0.3738 & 0.7539 & 0.2291\\
 5 & 108005.jpg & 0.8213 & 0.1583 & 0.7878 & 0.1477\\
 6 & 108082.jpg & 0.8572 & 0.0816 & 0.8296 & 0.0885\\
 7 & 109053.jpg & 0.9166 & 0.1930 & 0.8273 & 0.1682\\
 8 & 113044.jpg & 0.8967 & 0.2802 & 0.7997 & 0.1675\\
 9 & 123057.jpg & 0.9250 & 0.1407 & 0.8370 & 0.14906\\
10 & 130026.jpg & 0.8718 & 0.0879 & 0.8162 & 0.0770\\
11 & 160068.jpg & 0.8691 & 0.0968 & 0.8519 & 0.1166\\
12 &  16077.jpg & 0.8822 & 0.2614 & 0.7978 & 0.1866\\
13 & 163014.jpg & 0.9182 & 0.2778 & 0.8629 & 0.2020\\
14 & 163085.jpg & 0.8387 & 0.1144 & 0.8113 & 0.1778\\
15 & 167062.jpg & 0.8928 & 0.2264 & 0.9528 & 0.2685\\
16 & 196027.jpg & 0.9358 & 0.2596 & 0.9142 & 0.2472\\
17 & 247003.jpg & 0.8020 & 0.1571 & 0.7488 & 0.2289\\
18 & 253027.jpg & 0.8421 & 0.3308 & 0.8348 & 0.2869\\
19 & 291000.jpg & 0.7741 & 0.1585 & 0.6862 & 0.1015\\
20 & 296007.jpg & 0.9638 & 0.1927 & 0.8589 & 0.1119\\
21 & 304034.jpg & 0.7805 & 0.2185 & 0.7024 & 0.1522\\
22 & 326038.jpg & 0.8490 & 0.3106 & 0.7688 & 0.1652\\
23 & 326085.jpg & 0.8739 & 0.1824 & 0.7880 & 0.09560\\
24 &  38092.jpg & 0.8941 & 0.4058 & 0.8103 & 0.2324\\
25 &  41033.jpg & 0.9461 & 0.2834 & 0.8725 & 0.1701\\
26 &  42049.jpg & 0.9506 & 0.5688 & 0.9260 & 0.3500\\
27 &  43074.jpg & 0.9004 & 0.2247 & 0.8771 & 0.1814\\
28 &  69015.jpg & 0.7865 & 0.3290 & 0.7787 & 0.2924\\
29 &  69040.jpg & 0.7371 & 0.0876 & 0.7128 & 0.1199\\
30 &   8023.jpg & 0.9478 & 0.0895 & 0.8611 & 0.1016\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{This is the caption}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
%       \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
            \small
            \begin{tabular}{crSSSS}
            &&  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\large MP}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\large Canny}\\
                \hline
                Img. &Imagine BSBD& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Acc}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef  Dice}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Acc} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef Dice}\\ 
                \hline
                1 & 103070.jpg &   0.9017 &0.1789  &0.8298 & 0.1767\\
                 2 & 104055.jpg & 0.9238 &0.2694  &0.8530 &0.1864\\
                 3 & 106025.jpg & 0.9391 &0.2594 &0.9487 &0.2145\\
                 4 & 108004.jpg & 0.8563 &0.3738 &0.7539 &0.2291\\
                 5 & 108005.jpg & 0.8213 &0.1583 &0.7878 &0.1477\\
                 6 & 108082.jpg & 0.8572 &0.0816 &0.8296 &0.0885\\
                 7 &  109053.jpg &0.9166 & 0.1930 &0.8273 &0.1682\\
                8 &  113044.jpg & 0.8967 &0.2802 &0.7997 &0.1675\\
                 9 & 123057.jpg &0.9250 & 0.1407 &0.8370 &0.14906\\
                 10 & 130026.jpg & 0.8718 &0.0879 &0.8162 &0.0770\\
                 11 & 160068.jpg & 0.8691 &0.0968 &0.8519 &0.1166\\
                  12 & 16077.jpg & 0.8822 &0.2614 &0.7978 &0.1866\\
                  13 & 163014.jpg & 0.9182 &0.2778 &0.8629 &0.2020\\
                 14 & 163085.jpg &0.8387 &0.1144 &0.8113 &0.1778\\
                  15 & 167062.jpg &0.8928 &0.2264 &0.9528 &0.2685\\
                  16 & 196027.jpg & 0.9358 &0.2596 &0.9142 &0.2472\\
                  17 & 247003.jpg & 0.8020 &0.1571 &0.7488 &0.2289\\
                  18 & 253027.jpg & 0.8421 &0.3308 &0.8348 &0.2869\\
                  19 & 291000.jpg & 0.7741 &0.1585 &0.6862 &0.1015\\
                 20 & 296007.jpg & 0.9638 &0.1927 &0.8589 &0.1119\\
                  21 & 304034.jpg &0.7805 &0.2185  & 0.7024 & 0.1522\\
                 22& 326038.jpg  &0.8490 &0.3106  &0.7688 &0.1652\\
                 23& 326085.jpg &0.8739 &0.1824 &0.7880 &0.09560\\
                 24& 38092.jpg &0.8941 &0.4058 &0.8103 &0.2324\\
                 25 & 41033.jpg &0.9461 &0.2834&0.8725 &0.1701\\
                 26&  42049.jpg &0.9506 &0.5688&0.9260 &0.3500\\
                 27& 43074.jpg &0.9004 &0.2247 &0.8771 &0.1814\\
                 28& 69015.jpg &0.7865 &0.3290 & 0.7787 &0.2924\\
                 29& 69040.jpg &0.7371 &0.0876  &0.7128 &0.1199\\
                 30 & 8023.jpg &0.9478 &0.0895  &0.8611 &0.1016\\
                \hline 
            \end{tabular}
%       \end{adjustbox}
        \caption{.}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```